# VBA - Possibility of saying that SheetChange in specific Range is "something like True"?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

First, I must admit that I am completely newbie here and in VBA mostly too. Thank you for this forum! :)

I have program that reacts on SheetChange to save the data. However, if there is formula added by macro, it doesn't cause the SheetChange. Copying and inserting as values isn't possible - there are 7k rows and the program acts on every SheetChange (colors and other stuff) - the time is not bearable.

Is there any possibility to have `EnableEvents = False` (to turn of getting SheetChange), then specify the Range of the changed cells (always rather the whole column - there are 2 columns only that interest me) and then let the program save data. The coloring of the cells and so on would remain (this coloring and so on has to stay in the program)

Is it even possible that it would work? If it could, how should I tell the macro that specific Range has SheetChange?

Apologies if the question is totally stupid.

Thank you very much for reading at least.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code which you use ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick response!
If you mean the code of the program that reacts on the SheetChange it's sadly impossible :( 
It's implemented as Excel AddIn so I can call saving data (those spotted by SheetChange) by the macro. It's complex and very used program that can't be edited easily because of this specific problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In the sheet change event, just specify that it should only save when `Target` is within the specified range.  For the formulas, use the `Calculate` event and repeat essentially the same code.

So, if you only want it to save when the changed cell is in the first column and only within a certain row range (for example), add `If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 5 And Target.Row <= 10 Then` to your change event.

For the Formula issue, add the following routine

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
 'your code here 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I'll try to get it and then to implement it :)